# Not able to install android APK file using eclipse

Tags: android, apk, installation

When trying to run android application from eclipse

console shows

```
[2012-01-31 14:01:01 - Remix_6Dec11] Android Launch!
[2012-01-31 14:01:01 - Remix_6Dec11] adb is running normally.
[2012-01-31 14:01:01 - Remix_6Dec11] Performing com.ideafarms.android.remix.SplashScreen activity launch
[2012-01-31 14:01:03 - Remix_6Dec11] Uploading Remix_6Dec11.apk onto device '0123456789ABCDEF'
[2012-01-31 14:01:03 - Remix_6Dec11] Installing test.apk...
```

nothing else , it keep continue to display installing message do not move forward and nothing is install on device.

i am sure that there is no problem in application cause it is happening with all the android application in eclipse workspace.

Comment: Have you tried to install it via command line? YOu can use 'adb install path' to manually install an apk file.

Comment: If you are only installing, then it is ok. Check your emulator, you should see the app installed and available in application list.

Comment: i am trying to debug my code and want to trace log cat file, my android device is connected by usb and detected in devices list, but when i try to debug as android application or run as android application then after selecting device from device list..its shown the above messages in console..it's happening with all the android applications i have in my eclipse workspace .

Comment: if installed already the project then try uninstall that project from emulator and install again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create unsigned version of your apk, then place it on SD card and install through fileManager... If it will work - so, the problem is in your settings of Eclipse... Try to reinstall droid sdk, usb drivers and adt...

Comment: Thanks,Issue has been solved by re-installing the android SDk

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it but its works for me on same problem ..

trace path on command "platfrom tools"

- adb kill-server
- adb start-server

and then try to run application .